# How do I reverse the order of a series of numbers that are generated from a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, binary, reverse

I have some code to convert decimal to binary but using the conversion method I have here the numbers will print in the reverse order of the correct binary. How can I reverse the result I get without changing my conversion method or removing the while loop? I was thinking of creating an array inside the loop then a for loop which would print out the numbers in reverse order but I have no clue how to do this with Java.

```
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int num = user.nextInt();

    while (num > 0) {
        int remainder = num % 2;
        num = num / 2;

         if(remainder > 0) {
             System.out.print("1");
         }else if (remainder == 0) {
            System.out.print("0");
         }else {

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to just build the string as you go:

```
String result = "";
while (num > 0) {
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        result = "0" + result;
    else
        result = "1" + result;
    num /= 2;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Good clear answer, simple and doesn't have that StringBuilder clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing it out immediately, save the output to a StringBuilder and then at completion [reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) it

**sample**

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder ();
int num = user.nextInt();

while (num > 0) {
    int remainder = num % 2;
    num = num / 2;

     if(remainder > 0) {
         buf.append("1");
     }else if (remainder == 0) {
        buf.append("0");
     }else {
         // not sure what your logic is here
     }
}
buf.reverse();
System.out.println (buf.toString());
```

**or**

as @billk alludes to you could insert the "0" or "1" string at position zero, so that in fact you are `prepending` the string not appending it.  Then you will not need to `reverse` the StringBuilder object

```
    while (num > 0) {
    int remainder = num % 2;
    num = num / 2;

     if(remainder > 0) {
         buf.insert(0, "1");
     }else if (remainder == 0) {
        buf.insert(0, "0");
     }else {
         // not sure what your logic is here
     }
}
System.out.println (buf.toString());
```

Comment: Or instead of appending try prepending--use"buf =  (remainder > 0 ? "1" : "0") + buf", also don't bother with StringBuilder/buffer except in extreme cases...

Answer (score 1):

The code below can be useful to convert 8 bit integer, 8-bit binary String

```
String.format(”%8s”, Integer.toBinaryString(x)).replace(’ ’, ’0’))
```

If you are already having code but you just need to reverse it, use StringBuilder class to store your string value and then use `reverse()` method of StringBuilder class.

More Detail Can be found regarding StringBuilder class below 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

Answer (score 0):

**Working code Using array:** You can use something like this if you want to do it with array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rev {
    private Scanner user;

    Rev() {
        user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num = user.nextInt();

        int binary[] = new int[40]; // you can use an array like this
        int index = 0;

        while (num > 0) {
            binary[index++] = num % 2;
            num = num / 2;
        }
        if (binary.length != 0) {
            for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.print(binary[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Rev();
    }

}
```